# How do I get two js functions to work together?

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, web, autologin

I want to use JS to login to a website and then change the URL to a different page on the same website. I have two functions and they both work on their own, but not together. I don't know how to write/organize these functions in such a way that one can execute after the other.

```
function autoLogin() {

document.getElementById("userName").value = "username";
document.getElementById("pwd").value = "password";
document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();

}
autoLogin();

function nextPage() {
window.location.replace("https://www.website.com/page2");
}

nextPage();
```

Comment: My guess would be that the browser navigates away from the page you're on when you click the login button, so `nextPage` never gets called

Comment: You are describing functionality the server would manage in the script you submit your form to.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a callback to your first function that calls the second function that you pass in.  For example:

```
function autoLogin(callback) {

    document.getElementById("userName").value = "username";
    document.getElementById("pwd").value = "password";
    document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
    callback();
}

function nextPage() {
    window.location.replace("https://www.website.com/page2");
}

autoLogin(nextPage);
```

This will depend on your LoginButton click doing something in the background synchronously though.  If you want to wait for whatever happens in the login to happen first, you might want to just call the function that gets called with the login button instead of actually triggering the click.  Then you can pass your callback into that function;

Let's say your LoginButton click calls a function called doLogin().  You add your callback to that function, and then check to see if it exists when it's called before you call it, to maintain backward compatibility.

```
function doLogin(callback) {
   // get username and password and then asynchronously login

   if (callback) {
      callback();
   }
}

function autoLogin(callback) {

    document.getElementById("userName").value = "username";
    document.getElementById("pwd").value = "password";
    doLogin(callback);
}

function nextPage() {
    window.location.replace("https://www.website.com/page2");
}

autoLogin(nextPage);  //This calls autoLogin, which passes the callback to doLogin.                  
                      //Once doLogin is done, it calls nextPage.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the below takes you to a new page.

```
document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
```

so, nextPage() won't get called.

Maybe, for the script that's loaded on page 2, you can have a conditional redirect to the page2, on page load.